# Difference between YUI 3.3 and YUI 3.7

Tags: performance, yui, yui3

I have a website that uses YUI 3.3.0 and YUI 2.9.0 (using YUI 2in3 project), right now I'm trying to improve performance in the initial load time of the site, I followed several tips that I found on the web, but I wonder if I have any improvement if I make an upgrade from YUI 3.3.0 to YUI 3.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the difference?  YUI 3.3.0 was released in January 2011, and 3.7.1 in September 2012, so that is ~20 months of work by the YUI team and community on the library that is missing (4 versions).  Since YUI has hundreds of modules, it's tough to pin-down exactly what changed that could affect your site. It could be very little, or it could be a lot.  It's very unlikely that an upgrade could slow-down your site, though.  Performance has always been a high priority for the project, so whenever performance wins can be had, they are taken.  For example, this recent 3.6.0->3.7.0 introduced some significant custom-event performance improvements ([source](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/08/31/yui-3-7-0pr1-event-performance/)).

You can take a peek through each release announcement to see if any of your specific needs were addressed:

- [3.4.0](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2011/08/18/announcing-yui-3-4-0-and-the-new-yuilibrary-com/)
- [3.5.0](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/04/10/announcing-yui-3-5-0/)
- [3.6.0](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/08/01/announcing-yui-3-6-0/)
- [3.7.0](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/09/18/announcing-yui-3-7-0/)

Also, stop by #yui on Freenode if you have any specific questions about your site and YUI performance.